# Sending email to some specific user

Tags: emails

is there any way to send email only to some specific joomla user ?

How to do that please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use an extension, what you can do is:

1. Create a new user group
2. Assign these specific users to you newly created group
3. In the Joomla backend, go to **Users** >> **Mass Mail Users**

Here you can select your newly created usergroup which will send an email to all users that belong to it.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I would use the free version of AcyMailing. This way you can create a queue of e-mails and avoid to be confused by a spammer for senidng too many e-mails at once.

Comment: Also, it is really nice that you can see if the user open the email and click on a ink inside

Comment: Thank you , but it is a very complex extension which includes mailing list support too. I need only a simply/small extension to send email to some specific joomla user

Comment: I am not a developer and I use it often without issues. Well, I had a bit of help from designers to tweak a template, but the standards ones are ok.
But no problem, just trying to help :)